# php move_uploaded_file not creating file

Tags: php

I am having a problem with `move_uploaded_file()`.

I am trying to upload a image path to a database, which is working perfectly and everything is being uploaded and stored into the database correctly.

However, for some reason the `move_uploaded_file` is not working at all, it does not produce the file in the directory where I want it to, in fact it doesn't produce any file at all.

The file uploaded in the form has a name of `leftfileToUpload` and this is the current code I am using.

```
 $filetemp = $_FILES['leftfileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
 $filename = $_FILES['leftfileToUpload']['name'];
 $filetype = $_FILES['leftfileToUpload']['type'];
 $filepath = "business-ads/".$filename;
```

This is the code for moving the uploaded file.

```
move_uploaded_file($filetemp, $filepath);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you enabled the write privileges of the directory?

Comment: Yes the permission is set to 777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$target_dir = "business-ads/";
$filepath = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["leftfileToUpload"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["leftfileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $filepath)
```

Reference - [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the real path to the directory you wish to upload to.

For instance "/var/www/html/website/business-ads/".$filename

Also make sure the web server has write access to the folder.

Comment: I tried that.. "/httpdocs/business-ads/" still doesn't do anything in there

Comment: What type of webserver are you running?

Comment: Plesk I believe the web server is

Comment: Not sure if this will help but have a look at teh output from this and see if it works for you, I don't have much knowledge of hosted server as I run my own. `<?php echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__)); ?>`

Comment: I have yes and it just states that its failed to open stream, there is no such file or directory.

Comment: Have a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021](Link)

Comment: I've tried that, I know the directory does exist with the correct permissions so I can't understand why it isn't copying them over to the directory

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your given path is correct in respect to your current file path.
you may use.

```
if (is_dir("business-ads"))
{
    move_uploaded_file($filetemp, $filepath);
} else {
    die('directory not found.');
}
```

Comment: It states that the directory is not found, however I know that it is there?

Comment: is "business-ads" directory and the php page is exists in same folder?

Comment: They do yes, removing the `.$filename` from the end of the `$filepath` variable, it finds the directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to check following details :

1) Check your directory "business-ads" exist or not.

2) Check your directory "business-ads" has permission to write files.

You need to give permission to write in that folder.

Comment: The directory has permission 777